How to keep the source HTTP headers when redirecting with a CNAME DNS record
We have a site hosted in Cloudflare pages, it sets some headers using a CF worker, all good. But one of our older domains is registered and managed by goddady and we cannot move it for now, it has a CNAME record poiting to CF and everything works fine. The issue is that we lose the request headers, for example X-Frame-Options.
Is it possible to keep the source headers when using a CNAME considering the DNS is managed by Godaddy and not CF and a CF worker cannot inject the header there?
